# Getting ActionContext from HttpTrigger Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

If i have an azure function with an httptrigger is there a way to get the ActionContext?  There is the IActionContextAccessor interface i can register as a singleton...but nothing in the azure function runtime seems to actually set it for each request so it's seems unable to achieve what i'm after.

i'm making the assumption there is an underlying actioncontext to be got in the case of an HttpTrigger function..that may be a bad assumption.

Comment: What data are you wanting your function to be able to access?

Comment: i'm building up a ViewContext to pass to razor and part of that is an actioncontext, i was wondering if there was one already present i can use instead of building my own off of the HttpContext

Comment: Have you come across [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1539) yet?

Comment: yeah, the sample repo at the end i've contributed to actually, but i'm a few generations beyond it now trying to connect az functions routing to razor...that stuff was all just about using razor all as a template